# How to view a picture from a byte array that contains a zip-compressed file?

Tags: c#, image, zip, archive

I'm working on a program in *C#* that can view the content of encrypted *ZIP* files without having to extract them. So keep in mind, I really don't want to write to any directory file or the encrypted zip. With encrypted I mean there is a byte shifting encryption on the file headers.

I have a loop that decrypts the file headers. So then I have the File Header and Data (compressed). Now let's say there is only 1 file in the ZIP (Image). How can I display this image in a picturebox? I tried to fill a byte array with the decrypted bytes and then view 1 file from it with the `DotNetZip` library. But when I write/read the ZIP from byte array it says it's broken (I gues I messed up the file format?). Is there any way I can view the compressed file in a picturebox?

Comment: Get the decompressed stream and create a `Bitmap` object? Not quite sure what you are asking...

Comment: You have two issues here: 1) extract file of image from archive 2) display image on a screen. Looks like you can perform first task successfully. To display image just use classes from assembly `System.Drawing`.

Comment: I'm gonna try to put the file in a memorystream and then decrypt the memorystream instead of decrypting a byte array. So I can then use the memorystream to display the picture.